# How can I give Token-Customers access to a bunch of files that are not on the Blockchain? (Ethereum)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

At first I was thinking about simply letting them see a Google Drive link but that would have to stay the same so the customers could just send the link to one another, even though the people should have to use the smart contract to get it.

Comment: Use something like ipfs or swarm to store the link, and use a gateway to serve the content

Comment: @RaghavSood I am bound to the Ropsten Network, I think they don't offer it on the testnet right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with https://ipfs.io (a distributed file store) and an Ethereum DApp. Given that you mention that you want to require people to use a smart contract to get access to the file, I think you'll want to encrypt the file before storing on IPFS. Because the IPFS is distributed, anyone could get the file if they know it exists but only someone with access to the private key could read it.

When the conditions of the smart contract have been met, you can release the key. Because an Ethereum smart contract can't do the actual decryption, your web3 app would need to do this part.

For example, in the web3 app after the file is stored on the IPFS:

```
addNewFile: function() {
    // encrypt the file
    var encryptedFile = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(fileData, passPhrase);
    // store on the IPFS
    ipfs.files.write( ... => {
        // make sure it worked
        ...
        // (fileName is an IPFS-generated hash uniquely identifying the (encrypted) file
        // write it to the contract
        deployedFileContract.AddFileEntry(fileLocation, fileName, passPhrase, function(error) {
            // respond to error condition
        });
    });
};

retrieveEncyptedFile: function() { 
    ...
    deployedFileContract.RetrieveFileEntry.call(_pointer-to-file_, function(error, result) {
        // fetch an encrypted file as a readable stream from IPFS

        // decrypt it and probably do something funky with mime types to make sure it gets saved
        var decryptedFile =  CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedFileStream, passPhrase). ...

    });
...
};
```

All up you would need your Solidity smart contract and a web3 app. You might run the IPFS js-client https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs in the browser, or access it via Nodejs or Go.